# Having trouble with the Heatmap's (Kernel Density Estimation-KDE) interpretation in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, interpolation, contour, heat-map, kernel-density

i wanted to generate a density/concentration map of a parameter, in this case Carbon percentage in a water sample. The dataset in csv file looks like these :

[image]

So, I imported the csv file then plotted the points, later i used heatmap with following criteria:

[image]

Finally I extracted contour from raster > extraction > contour :

[image]

My final product is this image:

[image]

I do not have much technical or theoretical knowledge on KDE, but my question is why are the contour values (labels-bold, italic) are varying from the original point values (green diamond) ? As you can see in the csv file, all values are between 0.4 to 0.6, but there are higher values in the heatmap. Is it because the whole process is estimating or interpolating the surrounding values ? If that is the case, how accurate are these estimations ?

I am looking to get a simple filled contour plot, which i usually do with R or Pyferret. I was wondering if the heatmap is the best way to generate simple filled contour plots, widely used in oceanography, like these:

[image]